# Turning a single MultiPolygon into many small polygons?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, polygon, multipart, singlepart

I have a large GeoJSON file with a single very complex MultiPolygon, and I would like to turn it into an identical file with many small polygons.

How can I do this? I can use `ogr2ogr` or `mapshaper` or PostGIS, or any other command-line tool.

This is what my file looks like:

[image]

Comment: If you want to use QGIS this is very quick using the multipart to singleparts tool.

Comment: Thanks! My source file is actually about 9GB(!) so I'd prefer to use something command line.

Comment: Ah I see, I haven't done it before so I have no idea if it would work for you but you might want to have a look at [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29580/how-to-run-a-simple-python-script-for-qgis-from-outside-e-g-sublime-text/29597) and see if it helps at all.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using PostGIS and doing `CREATE TABLE polygon_table AS SELECT id (ST_Dump(geom)).geom::geometry(Polygon,27700) AS geom FROM multipolygon_table`.

Comment: @Richard would you post your findings as an answer and accept it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As OP [figured out](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/307959/turn-a-single-multipolygon-into-many-small-polygons#comment498546_307959), the [ST_Dump](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Dump.html) function from PostGIS is one way to explode multipart geometries to single ones:

> When the input geometry is a collection or multi it will return a record for each of the collection components, ... .
>
> ST_Dump is useful for expanding geometries. ... . For example it can be use to expand MULTIPOLYGONS into POLYGONS.

```sql
SELECT sometable.field1, 
       (ST_Dump(sometable.the_geom)).geom AS the_geom
FROM sometable;
```

---

The following is a related post with Python alternatives: [Converting huge multipolygon to polygons](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/112095/converting-huge-multipolygon-to-polygons)

Answer (score 4):

To convert multipolygons to polygons with `ST_Dump`

```
CREATE TABLE polytable AS 
SELECT 
id, (ST_Dump(w.geometry)).geom::geometry(Polygon,25833) AS geom 
FROM 
table_multi w
```